# Calculate Time Difference in excel VBA and show results by the minute

Tags: excel, vba, time

Im looking for a way to calculate the time difference between two text box with time/ date value. Here is what i have :

```
Sub Calculatediff()

Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date

Dim totalminutes As Integer

date1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").TextBox1.Value
date2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").TextBox2.Value

totalminutes = DateDiff("n", date1, date2)
Dim hours As Integer
hours = totalminutes / 60

Dim minutes As Integer
minutes = (totalminutes Mod 60)

Dim sMessage
sMessage = totalminutes & " minutes = " & hours & " hours " & minutes & " minutes"
MsgBox sMessage, vbInformation, "Information"

End Sub
```

The problem is if i calculate 6:30 & 8:00 the result is 2 Hours and 30 Minutes which is wrong.

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However if ever that works it would only give out the minutes. Im looking for a result like 1 Hour 30 Minutes.

Comment: and "N" signifies minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my desired results as per the below :

```
Sub A()


Dim EDay As Date
Dim ETime As Date
Dim DtgA As Date
Dim FMessage

EDay = Format(CDate(Replace(Worksheets("Calculate Time").Range("D4").Value, ".", "/")), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
ETime = Format(Worksheets("Calculate Time").TextBox13.Value, "hh:mm:ss")
DtgA = EDay + ETime

Dim EDay2 As Date
Dim ETime2 As Date
Dim DtgB As Date

EDay2 = Format(CDate(Replace(Worksheets("Calculate Time").Range("G4").Value, ".", "/")), "dd-mmm-yyyy")
ETime2 = Format(Worksheets("Calculate Time").TextBox14.Value, "hh:mm:ss")
DtgB = EDay2 + ETime2

Dim result As Date
 result = Format(DateDiff("s", DtgA, DtgB) / (60 * 60) / 24, "hh:mm:ss")

'MsgBox "Date 1: " & DtgA & vbNewLine & "Date 2: " & DtgB & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & DateDiff("s", DtgA, DtgB) / (60 * 60) & vbNewLine & result
FMessage = DateDiff("s", DtgA, DtgB) / (60 * 60) & " Hours"

Worksheets("Calculate Time").TextBox16.Value = FMessage
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Format()` for this:

```vb
Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date
    
d1 = [F20] 'dat-time in F20 and F21
d2 = [f21]
    
'need to escape d, h, m, s, n in the format string with with "\"
Debug.Print Format(d2 - d1, "h \hour\s a\n\d m \mi\nute\s")
```